# Can you access git remote via another PC

Tags: git

I have 3 PCs A, B and C. A and C are connected to B but not each other. C has the git server (remote) and I want to work on A using push and pulls to C. All three are Linux. Can you set git up to access a remote via a pc?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by accessing the B computer from A using SSH.

You can access B computer by:

> ssh your_user@b_pc_ip_address

Then you can use Vim editor in the B pc to make your changes, and than commit and push to C, you can also use scp to transfer your files from computer A to computer B.

And if you use VSCode, you can also connect VSCode from computer A to B using ssh, and then in computer B you can push to C.

To see how to use VSCode for this please check: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh